# Date Conversion in Javascript?

Tags: date, sapui5, type-conversion

I have date variable in sapui5 like this :

> "Fri Jan 01 1960 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time)"

But i need to

> "01.01.1960"

format .How can i do that?Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard [date format](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/bc4114a88e4d4ac1a0f53b2a7a92b226.html) in sapui5.

In your case the coding will look like this:

```
sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern: "d.M.YYYY"}).format(inputdate);
```

But the better approach would be to let the system choose the date format pattern based on user's locale:

```
sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({style: "medium"}).format(inputdate);
```

Comment: Even better: Replace `pattern: "d.M.YYYY"` with `style: "medium"` and it works all over the world ;)

Comment: Completely agree, gave an answer assuming that guy wants exact pattern for some reason :)